# asp.net web forms get HTML Select value in code behind

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms, codeblocks

I'm creating HTML select in code-blocks

```
 Response.Write("<p>Mark: </p><select onChange=\"removeSameValue("+dzielo.URL+")\" id=\"" + dzielo.URL + "\" name =\""+ dzielo.URL + "\" class=\"form-control\">");
             Response.Write("<option value=\"--wybierz--\">--wybierz--</option>");
             for (int i = 1; i <= dziela.Count; i++)
             {
                 int j = i+1;
               Response.Write("<option value=\"" + j + "\">" + i + "</option>");
             }
                 Response.Write("</select>");
```

After a button click i'm trying to get a selected value from this Select tag:

```
protected void vote_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach(Dzieło dzielo in dziela){
               String ocena = Request.Form[dzielo.URL];
                ocenyDziel.Add(dzielo.Id_dzieło,int.Parse(ocena));

            }
 }
```

But it always returns null. When I create HTML select not in code block I'm allowed to get it that way. Is it any solution to get the value from Select which is created in code block? I don't want to make a Select `runat="server"`.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "in a code block"?  Between your "working" and "not working" version of the HTML `select`, is there any difference in the client-side code?

Answer (score 0):

We could use some more details to answer this more clearly but I suspect that since you are doing a response.write you are losing the state after the initial response back. I would assume that your original select control was hard coded into your .aspx page and that's why you can still see it with the Forms.Request method.

You can try throwing this code in during your Page_Init function and see if this fixes your problem and if not I would set the selected value via a server backed hidden field so you can access it in your code behind since you are posting back with a button click at that anyway.